# Need help adding an object to my array list, whenever it changes

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

It may sound confusing at first, but i got this code

```
const updateFav = (value, index) => {
  const tempData = _.cloneDeep(listProyectos);
  console.log(tempData);
  tempData[index].fav = value;
  setListProyectos(tempData);
};

const listaFavoritos = _.filter(listProyectos, item => item.fav);
const finalObject = listaFavoritos;//{[thisParam]:listaFavoritos};
```

i got a flatlist with an array with several items inside, and a dropdown menu where i select an item and depending on the id, it'll match the items with id of the flatlist object, the thing is, the items in flat list will display switches, and the code from updateFav, will save the value from the switches, and the whole idea, is whenever i switch on an element from the flatlist, it'll save it in a ListProyectos array.

the _.filter will get rid of all the elements that DO NOT contain the fav: true

So here is the problem, whenever i change the item from the dropdown, and change the flatlist, the whole listProyectos array get's replaced and i only see the last change i did.

here is the code for the dropdown

```
<ModalDropdown
  defaultValue={'Seleccionar'}
  onSelect={async (index, value) => 
    {
      await ParametersBusiness.GetInstance().getProjectClients(value);
      setListProyectos(DataManager.ResponseProjectClient);
    }
  }
  options={DataManager.ListCliente}
/>
```

and here the flatlist

```
<FlatList
  data={listProyectos}
  renderItem={({item, index}) => (
```

images to show what the actual problem is

[image]

ok the so when i switch on that project from that client, it saves the project to a new object, everything is fine there, BUT.

[image]

notice when i select a different client and switch another project, ONLY the LAST one i switched is saved, instead of both

gif where i select many projects from different clients

[image]

Comment: Why do you call the setListProyectos inside dropdown change ? wont it replace the whole array ?

Comment: what's the best approach for that? on a different state?

Comment: ok so you get new items everytime you change the dropdown and you want items from all different options to be available ?

Comment: exactly, here is the thing, the dropdown shows clients, and the flatlist the projects related to that specific client, so when i click on a project from a client, is saved in the new object, but when i want to add a new project from a different client, the latest project will be replaced by this new project

Comment: ok here is what i understand, you have a client list which is a dropdown and when you change you display projects based on that and you can chose some using a switch. I'm still not getting the issue after this :(

Comment: correct, my issue is that whenever i click on a project, and change client to pick a different project, instead of saving both projects in the new object, is only saving the last one i picked

Comment: notice how in the console log, is only saving one object instead of both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215137/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-nicolas-silva).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better have a separate state to store all fav items
like below

```
const updateFav = (value, index) => {
  const tempData = _.cloneDeep(listProyectos);
  tempData[index].fav = value;
  setListProyectos(tempData);
  setListProyectos(DataManager.FavoriteList);

  const allFavItems = [...favItems];
  allFavItems.push(tempData[index]);
  setFavItems(allFavItems);
};
const [favItems,setFavItems]= useState([]); should be on top
```

Comment: this function await ParametersBusiness.GetInstance().getProjectClients(value); what does is, i pass the client i selected from the dropdown as parameter, so it returns me the list of projects related to that client, i don't think setListProyectos(_.uniq([...listProyectos,...DataManager.ResponseProjectClient])); should go below that line

Comment: 'so it returns me the list of projects related to that client,' so do you want to show only projects for that client or all clients ?

Comment: forget about that part, is already doing that, what i want is, let me post a video to show what the issue actually is

Comment: all clients, let me post some pictures, because the video i recorded is 26mb converted to gif :(

Comment: If you can explain the problem it will be easy

Comment: const updateFav = (value, index) => {
  const tempData = _.cloneDeep(listProyectos);
  console.log(tempData);
  tempData[index].fav = value;
  setListProyectos(tempData);
};                 this is the code i'm using to switch and save the item with a fav key and true value,

Answer (score -1):

React works with immutable arrays. You can only change a array if you replace it all. Take a look at this: https://blog.logrocket.com/immutability-in-react-ebe55253a1cc